# WCF generated proxy does not contain *Specified property flags for WSDL string fields with minoccurs="0"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I've noticed that the WCF proxy generator is not generating the "specified" property flags for string fields

EG When I have two fields on a complexType specified in the WSDL:

```
<xs:element name="testStringField" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
<xs:element name="testDecimalField" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
```

the proxy generator will create these properties on the class for the complexType:

```
testStringField
testDecimalField
testDecimalFieldSpecified
```

Why no *Specified property for strings? How can I get svcutil to generate this?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'm being dumb. This is obviously because string is a reference type so there is no need to specify whether is included because the testStringField can be set to null, whereas testDecimalField cannot, hence the need for a testDecimalFieldSpecified flag.